# Change gain of hand tracking in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I would like to change the gain of the hand tracking in Unity but I have some problems when I try to move the hand.
Indeed, when I try to move the right hand, there is an error telling me the position of the hand is infinity. Do you have an idea about that ? I saw lots of things in forums but I don't understand what is the problem.

Here is my code :

```
    // Variables
    public GameObject hand;
    public GameObject handRenderer;
    private Vector3 posOrigin;

    // Settings
    public float gain;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        Vector3 posOrigin = handRenderer.transform.position;
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        float dx = transfo(handRenderer.transform.position.x, posOrigin.x);
        float dz = transfo(handRenderer.transform.position.z, posOrigin.z);
        hand.transform.position = new Vector3(posOrigin.x + dx, 0, posOrigin.z + dz);
    }

    float transfo ( float origin, float actual )
    {
        return gain * (actual - origin);
    }
```

The hand renderer is the point I take for my calcul because it does not work with the object RightHand directly.
Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all in `Start` in

```
Vector3 posOrigin = handRenderer.transform.position;
```

you are creating a new **local variable**.

You rather wanted to assign your class field

```
void Start()
{
    posOrigin = handRenderer.transform.position;
}
```

and then the `transfo` seems to be used inverted .. it should always be

```
current - original
```

but you are passing in first the current one and then the original which results in

```
original - current
```

I think in general you should rather do this in a single step and instead of the method rather use e.g.

```
var delta = handRenderer.transform.position - posOrigin;
var sizedDelta = delta * gain;
sizedDelta.y = 0;
hand.transform.position = posOrigin + sizedDelta;
```

---

Then make sure you haven't by accident the same object referenced in `hand` and `handRenderer` or that `handRenderer` isn't somewhere nested under `hand`.

Otherwise whenever you move the `hand` in your `Update` you also move the `handRenderer` the calculation is based on => Example

- Init at 0,0,0 with gain = 2
- moves handRenderer to `1,1,1`
- => moves hand to `2,2,2`
- moves hanRenderer along to now `3,3,3`
- => next frame moves hand to `6,6,6`
- mves handRenderer along to now `9, 9, 9`
- => next frame moves hand to `18,18,18`
- .....

Comment: I changed it and I have 2 result. First, it is not laggy at the beginning right now. But in few seconds after the start of the programm, I have the error, transform.position assign attempt for 'RightHand' is not valid. Input position is { 47127451435287285372360541053076373504.000000, 0.000000, Infinity }.
UnityEngine.Transform:set_position (UnityEngine.Vector3)

Comment: can you confirm that the bottom is **not** the case and `handRenderer` is not nested under `hand`? It seems the case to me ..

Comment: My hand renderer is under my RightHand object. This is probably the problem. But how can I create a marker on top of rightHand which can follow this hand in real time ?

Comment: It may not be nested under the same object otherwise it is always moved along while you re moving the `hand`. Place it somewhere else in your scene hierarchy

Comment: I changed that but my hand does not move because this marker does not move in real time with the hand. Maybe if I create an object linked to this hand I will be able to move the hand ?
The problem is I don't know why I can't move the RightHand object directly. When I only use hand in my calcul it does not have any effect

Comment: I succeed thanks a lot for your help :)